# jquery textbox focus out not firing

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Given this markup (MVC5)

```
  @Html.HiddenFor(m =>m.Val1, new {id="answer_val1"})
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Val2, new { id = "answer_val2" })
```

Which produces the following;

```
 <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Val1 must be a number." data-val-required="The Val1 field is required." id="answer_val1" name="Val1" type="hidden" value="6" />

 <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Val2 must be a number." data-val-required="The Val2 field is required." id="answer_val2" name="Val2" type="hidden" value="9" />
```

I create a string that is used as the placeholder for the textbox where the answer gets input.

```
@{
    var answerPlaceholder = @"What is " + @Model.Val1 + "+ " +
    @Model.Val2 + "?";
}
```

Textbox markup

```
<div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Answer, new { @class = "col-xs-3 control-label" })  
  <div class="col-xs-5">
       @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Answer, new
       {
           @class = "form-control",
           @placeholder = answerPlaceholder,
           id = "answer",
           maxlength = 2
        })
   </div>
</div>
  <div class="form-group">
       <div class="col-xs-3" style="margin-left: 242px;">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default disabled" id="Send" name="Send" value="Send">
        </div>
  </div>
```

And these are the scripts which all load at the end of the document.
Clearly, at the very least, once the user enters the answer textbox, the button should turn green (btn-success) but nothing happens. I am trying to enable the button upon an accurate answer of the question.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#answer').focusin(function () {
       $('#Send').removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-success');
    });
    $('#answer').focusout(function () {
        var sum = parseInt('#answer_val1').val() + parseInt('#answer_val2').val();
        if (parseInt('#answer').val() === sum) {
            $('#Send').removeClass('disabled');
        }
    });
});
</script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>
```

**Working script**
I put the script in a file and rendered it in the script section. It is now working per Rahul

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#answer").on("focusin", (function () {
        $("#Send").removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-success");
    }));
    $("#answer").on("focusout", (function () {
        var sum = parseInt($("#answer_val1").val(), 10)
        + parseInt($("#answer_val2").val(), 10);
        if (parseInt($("#answer").val(), 10) === sum) {
            $("#Send").removeClass("disabled");
        }
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing the jQuery selector here

```
$('#answer').focusout(function () {
    var answer1 = parseInt($('#answer_val1').val(), 10);
    var answer2 = parseInt($('#answer_val2').val(), 10);
    var sum = answer1 + answer2;
    if (answer1 === sum) {
        $('#Send').removeClass('disabled');
    }
});
```

[Working demo for focusin](http://jsfiddle.net/jo7d9kd9/)

***Edit***

Your script is rendering before the jQuery core file. Please change the order.

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#answer').focusin(function () {
       $('#Send').removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-success');
    });
    $('#answer').focusout(function () {
        var sum = parseInt('#answer_val1').val() + parseInt('#answer_val2').val();
        if (parseInt('#answer').val() === sum) {
            $('#Send').removeClass('disabled');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: good catch, but the first function SHOULD change the button to green (btn-success) and nothing happens

Comment: Please check whether you are getting any error in console. Its working fine for me.

Comment: i moved the script to a file and rendered it in the scripts section and now it works fine. In you example tho, the focusout could never work because answer1 cant ever equal sum. I posted the final working code in the post. I see you changed it while I was writing this but it still should be parseInt($("#answer").val(),10)

Answer (score 1):

Please change it to `blur()`:

```
$('#answer').blur(function () {
    var sum = parseInt($('#answer_val1').val()) + parseInt($('#answer_val2').val());
    if (parseInt('#answer').val() === sum) {
        $('#Send').removeClass('disabled');
    }
});
```

Comment: I was using blur first, that doesn't work either. Its as if JQuery not even loaded but it is, I checked in chrome dev tools

Comment: @dinotom `parseInt($('#answer_val1').val()) + parseInt($('#answer_val2').val())` - Use this. Try that.